# How can I launch Finder in a specific directory, from Automator or AppleScript?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, automator

I'm trying to assign a global keyboard shortcut that will launch a new window of Finder, in a specific directory. I can write a script that'll open a new Finder, but not sure how to make it open in a specific directory.

Any ideas how to do this with either Automator or AppleScript?

In case it's relevant, I have OS X Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As shell script:

```
open /Users/danielbeck/Documents
```

As AppleScript:

```
tell application "Finder"
    # Classic Mac OS syntax
    open alias "Macintosh HD:Users:danielbeck:Pictures"

    # Unix syntax
    open POSIX file "/Users/danielbeck/Downloads"
end tell
```

Wrap in an Automator *service* and assign a keyboard shortcut in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*.

[image: Automator screenshot]

---

For a pure Automator solution without script code, combine the *Get Specified Finder Items* and *Open Finder Items* actions. Drag & drop the desired folder to the list. Again, save and assign a keyboard shortcut in *System Preferences*.

[image: Automator screenshot]

Comment: Awesome, I went with the "script-less" approach, thank you for teaching me this!!

Comment: Can confirm this still works on Sonoma.